# Split long output into two columns

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, columns

Is there a simple utility or script to columnate the output from one of my scripts? I have data in some form:

```
A aldkhasdfljhaf
B klajsdfhalsdfh
C salkjsdjkladdag
D lseuiorlhisnflkc
E sdjklfhnslkdfhn
F kjhnakjshddnaskjdh
```

but if this becomes two long, write the data in the following form (where still vertically ordered):

```
A aldkhasdfljhaf    D lseuiorlhisnflkc
B klajsdfhalsdfh    E sdjklfhnslkdfhn
C salkjsdjkladdag   F kjhnakjshddnaskjdh
```

From reading the manpage, I don't think that this is something `column` would be appropriate for but I'm not sure. It's easy enough to split in the form:

```
A B 
C D 
E F
```

by only printing `\n` every second line (what my current script does). Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`column` seems to be what you want:

```
$ cat file
A aldkhasdfljhaf
B klajsdfhalsdfh
C salkjsdjkladdag
D lseuiorlhisnflkc
E sdjklfhnslkdfhn

$ column file
A aldkhasdfljhaf    D lseuiorlhisnflkc
B klajsdfhalsdfh    E sdjklfhnslkdfhn
C salkjsdjkladdag   F kjhnakjshddnaskjdh
```

Comment: I did try. But wrongly (with `-t)... But for yours to work reliably you probably need `--columns`.

Comment: I did try but for some reason I didn't realise that it depended on the width of your terminal window (seems obvious now)!

Comment: also I was testing this on two machines at once. Apparently the old version (circa 1993 on Scientific Linux) behaves differently to the newer 2004 version...

Answer (score 19):

To columnate the output, `pr` converts text files for printing:

```
-COLUMN, --columns=COLUMN: output COLUMN columns
      and print columns down, unless -a is used.

-t, --omit-header : omit page headers and trailers
```

e.g.

```
ls /etc | pr -2 -t
abrt                                gtk-2.0
acpi                                hal
adjtime                             hba.conf
agent.properties                    host.conf
aliases                             hosts
aliases.db                          hosts.allow
...
```

Comment: not working properly for large (long) file.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the file in two (with the same number of lines or the first file having one line more) and then do this:

```
paste file1 file2
```

If the length of the lines is too different then is may be necessary to use printf to adapth the lengths by padding with spaces.

Comment: Or `... | paste - -`  when "splitting long output"...

Answer (score 1):

You can use just plain `columns`:

```
$ cat test.txt | columns
A aldkhasdfljhaf             B klajsdfhalsdfh             C salkjsdjkladdag
D lseuiorlhisnflkc           E sdjklfhnslkdfhn            F kjhnakjshddnaskjdh
```

**NOTE:** the `columns` command is part of the `autogen` package on my Fedora 14 system.

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/columns
autogen-5.9.4-7.fc12.x86_64
```

#### References

- [GNU autogen project page](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/)

Comment: `columns: command not found`. [autogen](http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/)?

Comment: @Gilles - yes it's part of `autogen`. Just checked on my Fedora 14 system. I'll mention it in the answer as well.