# POSIX equivalent to column -t

Tags: posix, text-formatting

I was recently surprised to find out, that the POSIX
[list](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html)
of utilities doesn't include the
[`column`](https://man.openbsd.org/column.1)
utility.  `column` first appeared way back in 4.3BSD, and
it's is pretty useful.  Is there a POSIX equivalent of it?

---

The exact command I would like to replace is:

```
$ more -- ./tmp.txt 
1   SMALL   000a
2   VERY_VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG    000b
3   SMALL   000c
$ column -t -- ./tmp.txt 
1  SMALL                     000a
2  VERY_VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG  000b
3  SMALL                     000c
$
```

That is, expand tabs to create prettier columns.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138027

Comment: Why not just [compile it yourself](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/text-utils/column.c)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX prefers to codify existing behavior, and to only mandate new features or features that are not widely adopted when the existing behavior is unsatisfactory. Nowadays there isn't much call for presentation of data using unformatted text in fixed-width fonts, so `column` is unlikely to become mandatory. Unlike `pr`, it's from BSD, it isn't present System V and other historical unices, so it isn't grandfathered in.

Like any other text utility, you can express it in awk with a moderate amount of work. Here's a minimally tested implementation of `column -t`. Awk's `-F` option is similar to `column`'s `-s` in simple cases (with a single character).

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk
{
    if (max_column < NF) max_column = NF;
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (width[i] < length($i)) width[i] = length($i);
        data[NR, i] = $i;
    }
}
END {
    for (i = 1; i < max_column; i++) format[i] = sprintf("%%-%ds  ", width[i]);
    format[max_column] = "%s\n";
    for (k = 1; k <= NR; k++) {
        for (i = 1; i <= max_column; i++) printf format[i], data[k, i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!  Although I will probably replace the double space in `sprintf` with a tab, so that fullwidth characters (like the Han characters or emoji) don't screw up the alignment.

Comment: Gilles, will this also work if you use standard awk array[index1 SUBSEP index2] expressions instead of arrays of arrays?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Sure. I'd forgotten that was a gawk extension, thanks.

Comment: By `-v`, do you mean `-F`? The `-s` option to `column` sets a delimiter, like `-F`; the `-v` option to `awk` sets an variable within the context of `awk`, at least on my system.

Answer (score 4):

`pr` does a lot of what `column` does. If you specify an actual command line we can work on the replacement one.

> NAME
> pr - convert text files for printing
>
> SYNOPSIS
> pr [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> DESCRIPTION
> Paginate or columnate FILE(s) for printing.

For your particular case, you could use `awk`:

```
awk '{printf("%2s %30s %10s", $1, $2, $3);}' file.txt
```

Note that the width specifiers 2, 30 and 10 are hardcoded, you have to choose the values for your input, or read the file twice (once to get the maximum widths for each column and the second time to print it out with the values you got).

Comment: Thanks, I added more info.  I want a replacement for `column -t`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no direct equivalent to `column` among the POSIX set of utilities.

A possible (cheap) POSIX solution could be:

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <<"EOT" | pr -3 -a -t
1   SMALL   000a
2   VERY_VERY_VERY_VERY_LONG    000b
3   SMALL   000c
EOT
1                       SMALL                   000a
2                       VERY_VERY_VERY_VERY_LON 000b
3                       SMALL                   000
```

After copying/pasting it, your sample data had fields separated by spaces. In case they were actually separated by a single `TAB`, you can use `tr '\t' '\n'`.

Of course this assumes that all the input lines have the same number of fields. The rather evident downside is that columns are evenly sized, which make them look significantly less nice than the output of `column -t`.

Also, as shown in the above sample, `pr` uses a fixed length for lines (defaulting to 72 characters), and truncates fields that don't fit into their column's width. It may be then necessary to explicitly set the page width (`-w`) to a suitable value.