# "ls -l" but with output in more than one column?

Tags: command-line, files, ls

Monitors tend to be more wide than tall. When there's hundreds of files in a folder, `ls -l` and `ls -l | more` will only show you me maybe 100 files at a time, due to the lack of vertical space on the screen. But my screen has enough horizontal space to have at least three columns of `ls -l` output (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42QRL.png) for an example of `ls -l` output on my screen).

All suggestions to change the number of columns of `ls` output, such as:

```
ls -C
ls | col
ls --width=2
ls | xargs -n 
ls  --tabsize=2
ls  --format=vertical
```

seem not to improve my `ls -l` output.

I browsed all options given in `man ls`. **Is there any way to get the `ls -l` output, but multiple columns of it rather than one?** Even a two-column output would be so helpful!

Comment: @cryptarch Not really, because the highest voted answer suggested to do `column` followed by a second command, whereas `column ls` gives an error. I wouldn't call this a duplicate because we're asking for different things, and that question didn't come up in my the searches that I made prior to asking this question: multicolumn "ls -l", two column "ls -l", more than one column "ls -l", etc. The solution turned out to be be a hybrid between the lowest scored answer (append `| columns` to the end) and the highest voted answer (use `column` without the `s` at the beginning).

Comment: The highest-voted answer suggests to use `command` with a *file*, not a command. You can pipe input to `column` too, as you discovered.

Comment: @StephenKitt isn't that what my answer says?

Comment: Yes, that is what your answer says, but it seems to me you dismissed the linked answer based on a misunderstanding (`command ls`, which isn’t what the linked answer suggests). Note that a duplicate doesn’t mean that the *questions* are the same, just that the answers apply to both; and the fact that a question didn’t turn up in your searches doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be:

```
ls -l | column
```

Thank you cryptarch for [suggesting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732177/ls-l-but-with-output-in-more-than-one-column?noredirect=1#comment1389419_732177) this [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81757/78288)!

Comment: Ha, no worries. Personally I thought something like `pr -t -w180 -2` (similar to one of the answers) gives better output than `column`, but your call :)

Comment: @cryptarch thanks! The best I managed to get with `pr` was `ls -l -t | pr -t -w200 -3` which looks the same as `ls -l |column` but more squished. I haven't yet been able to get `ls -l -t | pr -t -wXXX -4` as I have to play around with the `XXX` value to make sure nothing gets cut-off. It seems to be a more powerful solution if used properly, but also  more complicated and screen-dependent.